# Unknown Piece - Looks like a train car

Tags: part-identification, piece-information

I found this piece in a tub of Lego; it looks like a train car. There is a hinge piece in the middle that tilts 90 degrees. I've looked at BrickLink & Brick owl to no avail. Can anyone help me identify this piece. I know it is Lego as it is stamped ©Lego Group on the back

[image: wheels orange, body - green, bumper - gray on 1 end & gray on the other end]

Answer (score 14):

It's
[Vehicle, Base 4 x 6 Racer Base with Orange Wheels](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=30558c06&name=Vehicle,%20Base%204%20x%206%20Racer%20Base%20with%20Orange%20Wheels&category=%5BVehicle,%20Base%5D#T=C)

(I found it on bricklink by searching for ["vehicle base"](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=vehicle%20base#T=A))

Comment: thanks for your help.